# Shortcut to put focus at end of value in cell

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to do this without using a mouse?

I'm in Google Sheets, with the focus on a specific cell, which already has content in it. I want the focus to move to the very end of the value in the cell so that I can start appending more content.

I've tried to find a way to do this without a mouse, but haven't found anything. It would sure save a lot of back and forth between keyboard/mouse.

Comment: Hi Tess, have you tried F2 + End? Double click right button mouse + End?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described the shortcut you are looking for is **<kbd>ARROW DOWN</kbd>** (if the cell is active)

[image]

- if the cell is not active: **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>** + **<kbd>ARROW DOWN</kbd>**
- if the formula/content of the cell is on more rows: **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>** + **<kbd>END</kbd>**
- also you can try **<kbd>F2</kbd>** + **<kbd>ARROW DOWN</kbd>**
- or ultimate shortcut **<kbd>F2</kbd>** + **<kbd>END</kbd>**

Comment: hm thanks, but that just moves the focus to the cell one below the starting cell. i want to stay on the same cell, but have the focus be at the end of the content within the cell.

Comment: Thanks those are great!

Answer (score 0):

If you press **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**, in any cell containing content, the cursor will move to the end of the content and you can start typing!